# Reactjs redirect from an action

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am trying to implement react router version 4. Please find the bare minimum code which I have now as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">TestUsers</h1>
                </header>
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>
                        Shelves
                        </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>
                        Products
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/add" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

I have been able to add a user successfully. I want to redirect to user's list page from the action which adds a user. Please find the action code below:

```
export function addUser(objData) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.post(
            'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users',
            {
                'name': objData.name,
                'email': objData.email
            }
        )
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ 'type': ADD_USER, 'payload': true });
                // TODO: programmatically redirect using react-router v4
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

I have been struggling to implement the same. Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Callback

```
export function addUser(objData, onSuccess, onFail) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return axios.post(
            'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users',
            {
                'name': objData.name,
                'email': objData.email
            }
        )
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ 'type': ADD_USER, 'payload': true });
                onSuccess()
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //you can handle error on your component
                onFail(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Then Call `addUser` like this on the component.

```
addUser(
   objData,
   () => this.props.history.push('/your-user-list-component'),
   () => {// handle the error here.}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could return Promise from your action:

```
export function addUser(objData) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return axios.post(
            'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users',
            {
                'name': objData.name,
                'email': objData.email
            }
        )
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ 'type': ADD_USER, 'payload': true });
                // TODO: programmatically redirect using react-router v4
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

then in a component:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.addUser(objData).then(() => {
    this.props.history.push('/somwhere')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.props.history.push('/some/path')` after dispatch action

I would also advise you to check if response.status is equal to 200

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history module.

Create history.js file

```
//history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
export default createHistory()
```

Update your router with the new history. You need to use Router instead of BrowserRouter.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

export default () => (
    <Router history={history}>
       ...
    </Router>
);
```

And now you can navigate programmatically.

```
import history from './history'
export function addUser(objData) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.post(
            'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users',
            {
                'name': objData.name,
                'email': objData.email
            }
        )
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ 'type': ADD_USER, 'payload': true });
                // TODO: programmatically redirect using react-router v4
               history.push(path)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-router 4, there was introduced `<Redirect />` component, which is returned in the `render()` method to achieve what you need. The redirect component is also imported from `react-router-dom` so: `import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  handleSubmit () {
    axios.post(/**/)
      .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

     if (redirect) {
       return <Redirect to='/somewhere'/>;
     }

     return <RenderYourForm/>;
}
```